# undefined reference to `uv_prepare_init' on libuv

Tags: libuv

Is `uv_prepare_init` deprecated?
In `uv.h` there is a function definition, but nowhere I could find the function body in C file. However, on documentation, there are no keyword, as *deprecated*.

Is there any solution to replace `uv_prepare_init`?
I need this handle for executing before polling I/O.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).

Answer (score 1):

`uv_prepare_init` isn't deprecated.
See the file [`loop-watcher.c`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/1a96fe33343f82721ba8bc93adb5a67ddcf70ec4/src/unix/loop-watcher.c) for more details. It's available both for unix (`libuv/src/unix`) and windows (`libuv/src/win`).

So, what's the magic?
How is it that there is no definition but the function is part of the library?
Macros. That's all. The definition is there, even though a bit obfuscated.

There exists a macro called [`UV_LOOP_WATCHER_DEFINE`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/1a96fe33343f82721ba8bc93adb5a67ddcf70ec4/src/unix/loop-watcher.c#L25), a part of which follows:

```
#define UV_LOOP_WATCHER_DEFINE(name, type) \
    int uv_##name##_init(uv_loop_t* loop, uv_##name##_t* handle) { \
        uv__handle_init(loop, (uv_handle_t*)handle, UV_##type); \
        handle->name##_cb = NULL; \
        return 0; \
    } \

    // ... continue ...
```

Immediately after the definition, [the macro is used](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/1a96fe33343f82721ba8bc93adb5a67ddcf70ec4/src/unix/loop-watcher.c#L66) as:

```
UV_LOOP_WATCHER_DEFINE(prepare, PREPARE)
```

You can easily do the substitution for yourself and find that it's actually defining `uv_prepare_init`.

Therefore we can say that the function is part of the library, it isn't deprecated (at least in `v1.x`) and you can freely use it for your purposes.
No need to *replace* it in any way.